# How to add comments on order after checkout

Tags: magento2

How I can allow the customer to add a comment after they place the order and checkout, from "My Orders" => "Order View Page" on the frontend?

because I need the customer to send the receipt after they transfer the money to my banking account.

Please note that I am using Magento 2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Override

`magento\vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates\order\info.phtml` in Your Theme. Put one form which containts textarea & submit button & in controller do below code

```
protected $order;

public function __construct(\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $order) {
    $this->order = $order;
}

public function execute() {

    $order = $this->order->get(1); // Your Order Id
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $comment = <get customer commment>;
    $order->addStatusHistoryComment($comment)->setIsCustomerNotified(false)->setEntityName('order')->save();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

create a controller:-

```
public function execute()
{
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('orderid');
    $orderObject = $this->order->create()->load($orderId);
    $comment = $params['comment'];
    $orderObject->addStatusHistoryComment($comment)->setIsCustomerNotified(false)->setEntityName('order')->save();
    $this->_redirect("sales/order/view/order_id/$orderId/");
}
```